# Scale svg based on zoom level on 2D

Tags: snap.svg, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How to know when the user is zooming in or out 2D dwg? I have a svg layer created with Snap.svg on top of the viewer. I would like to scale this layer based on the scale of the 2D drawing in the viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom tool to hook the user actions such as wheel input or gestures if you want to support mobile:

```
function AdnTool(viewer, toolName) {

  this.getNames = function() {

    return [toolName];
  };

  this.getName = function() {

    return toolName;
  };

  // ...

  this.handleWheelInput = function(delta) {

    console.log('-------------------');
    console.log('Tool:handleWheelInput(delta)');
    console.log(delta);

    return false;
  };

  this.handleGesture = function(event) {

    console.log('-------------------');
    console.log('Tool:handleGesture(event)');
    console.log(event);

    return false;
  };

  // ...
}
```

See there for a complete sample: [CustomTool Extension](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/blob/master/src/Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.CustomTool/Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.CustomTool.js)